# I want to select the value before and after the comma

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sql Query for select the value before and after the comma

There is a table called employee, there is 3 fields..Id,Name,Departmentid
In DepartmentId it consist of 3 id 201,301,401.

From this want to execute

```
Select * from employee where DepartmentId =301
```

Comment: Sounds like a terrible db design... think about normalization

Comment: Is it possible for 301 to appear as the first or third number in the `DepartmentId` or will it always be in the middle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work if you're always looking to match on the number in the middle, e.g. `301` in your example.

```
SELECT *
FROM employee
WHERE 
    SUBSTRING ( 
        DepartmentId, 
        CHARINDEX(',', DepartmentId, 0) + 1, 
        CHARINDEX(',', DepartmentId, CHARINDEX(',', DepartmentId, 0) + 1) - CHARINDEX(',', DepartmentId, 0) - 1
    ) = '301'
```

If `301` can be in any location in that field then you can just use `LIKE`

```
SELECT *
FROM employee
WHERE DepartmentId LIKE '%301%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE DEPARTMENTID LIKE '%301%'
```

Even if it works, I don't really understand how your DB is designed and why you need commas

Answer (score 0):

You can use `parsename()` function:

```
. . . 
where parsename(replace(DepartmentId, ',', '.'), 2) = 301;
```

However `like` predicate also useful:

```
. . . 
where DepartmentId LIKE '%301%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Comma seperated columns are an antipattern. You want to normalize your departments.

However, here's one way to do it:

```
select * from employee 
where '301' in (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(department, ','))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have departments like 1301 or 3011 then a simple LIKE might fail

Please check following SQL code

```
select * from employees where ','+departmentid+',' like '%,301,%'
```

And other option is to split departmentid column into each seperate department id value list

If you have a SQL Server before SQL Server 2016 then you need your own custome [SQL string split function](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/t-sql-convert-split-delimeted-string-as-rows-using-xml.aspx).
Then you can use following SQL query

```
select e.* 
from employees as e
cross apply dbo.split(departmentid,',') as s
where s.val = '301'
```

If you are working on SQL Server 2016 or SQL Server 2017, [string_split](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/split-string-function-in-sqlserver-2016.aspx) build-in SQL function can be used as follows again in a CROSS APPLY query

```
SELECT e.* 
FROM employees as e
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(departmentid, ',')
WHERE value = '301'
```

One last method can be using [SQL XML query](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/query-sql-server-database-table-xml-data-using-cross-apply.aspx) by modifying the comma seperated list into an XML data as follows

```
select 
    Id, Name, sqlXML.value('.','varchar(5)') as DepId
from (
    SELECT 
        Id, Name, 
        convert(xml, '<root><t>' + REPLACE(Departmentid, ',', '</t><t>') + '</t></root>') as dlist
    FROM employees
) tbl
CROSS APPLY dlist.nodes('/root/t') as XMLData(sqlXML)
WHERE sqlXML.value('.','varchar(5)') = '301'
```